# Oracle Race Conditions when doing select union select and insert

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert, union

I have an Oracle database and I am trying to programmatically determine if a view has the same number of records as the tables it draws from.  It may not because the view could be querying tables in another schema by mistake.  At first I tried doing

```
select count(*) from view
```

then doing

```
select count(*) from 
(select * from table1
 union 
select * from table2)
```

and comparing the results.

The problem is I'm worried about someone doing an insert into, say, table2 in the time between my first query and my second.  In that case I may have gotten 5 records from view, but after the insert is completed, I may get 6 records from the second query.

I don't want to falsely report a problem, so I thought about doing a union of the two queries:

```
select count(*) from view
union 
select count(*) from 
(select * from table1
union select * from table2)
```

But I don't know if this will actually prevent an insert from occurring between the query to the view and the query to the union of tables.

Basically I need to know if Oracle does the two selects on a snapshot of the data or if the data is dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single SQL statement in Oracle always sees the data that existed at a particular SCN (system change number).  Assuming the default transaction isolation level of read committed, that will be the SCN when the query starts.  So assuming pure SQL, both sides of the `UNION` would be determined on the data as of the SCN when the query started.

The caveat here would be if the view contains a call to PL/SQL (i.e. a function call that is used to determine whether to include a particular row).  Queries within the PL/SQL block will look at the current state of the data not necessarily the state it was in when the query started.

If you really only care about the number of rows returned, not the actual data, it would seem more logical to do something like

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM view) -
       (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM table) num_diffs
  FROM dual
```

If you really want to compare the data

```
SELECT <<columns>>
  FROM table
MINUS
SELECT <<columns>>
  FROM view
```

will show you the data from the table that does not exist i